# Unable to make my circular menu look like the image provided

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wearables, wearable-recyclerview

I can't find a tutorial to help me create a menu in Wearable `RecyclerView`. Everything that pops up up is related to `Recyclerview` for mobile phones. So I'm asking does the Wearable version work in the same manner or not?

I followed what was in the documentation but I don't know how to add items so that I would end up with something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**

So after messing around a bit and seeing the code for the `Recyclerview` here:https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/simple-recyclerview-java/part-2-adapter   (Very helpful by the way)

I managed to create a list of items. Problem is they're lined up vertically with large spaces between them. I have placed the lines of code in the documentation that were supposed to line them up like in the image but I don't know what the problem is.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.wear.ambient.AmbientModeSupport;
import androidx.wear.widget.WearableLinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class circular_menu_external extends FragmentActivity
        implements AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

//    Fragment toolsfragment = new Tools();
//    Fragment modesfragment = new Modes();
//    Fragment keysfragment = new Keys();
//    Fragment flowratefragment = new Flowrates();
  private WearableRecyclerView wearableRecyclerView;
  private Button btn;

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private WearableRecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circular_menu_external);

        wearableRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new MenuRecyclerViewAdapter(mExampleList);
        //Create a curved layout
        CustomScrollingLayoutCallback customScrollingLayoutCallback = new CustomScrollingLayoutCallback();
//        WearableLinearLayoutManager wearableLinearLayoutManager = new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this);
//        wearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(wearableLinearLayoutManager);
//        CustomScrollingLayoutCallback customScrollingLayoutCallback = new CustomScrollingLayoutCallback();
        wearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this, customScrollingLayoutCallback));

//        wearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this));
        wearableRecyclerView.setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(true);

        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    }

    private void action_1() {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(circular_menu_external.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
    private void action_2(){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(circular_menu_external.this, tool1mode1.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
    private void action_3(){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(circular_menu_external.this, tool1mode2.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
    private void action_4(){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(circular_menu_external.this, tool1mode3.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
    private void cancelMenu(){
        Intent i1 = new Intent(circular_menu_external.this, Main_menu.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallback getAmbientCallback() {
        return null;
    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.tool_ic, "Line 1", "Line 2"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.mode_ic, "Line 3", "Line 4"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.key, "Line 5", "Line 6"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.flow_ic, "Line 7", "Line 8"));
    }
    public void buildRecyclerView() {

        wearableRecyclerView.setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(true);
        wearableRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        wearableRecyclerView.setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MenuRecyclerViewAdapter(mExampleList);
        wearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        wearableRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        //Add a circular scrolling gesture
        wearableRecyclerView.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);
        wearableRecyclerView.setBezelFraction(0.5f);
        wearableRecyclerView.setScrollDegreesPerScreen(90);
    }
    


    public class CustomScrollingLayoutCallback extends WearableLinearLayoutManager.LayoutCallback {
        /** How much should we scale the icon at most. */
        private static final float MAX_ICON_PROGRESS = 0.65f;

        private float progressToCenter;

        @Override
        public void onLayoutFinished(View child, RecyclerView parent) {

            // Figure out % progress from top to bottom
            float centerOffset = ((float) child.getHeight() / 2.0f) / (float) parent.getHeight();
            float yRelativeToCenterOffset = (child.getY() / parent.getHeight()) + centerOffset;

            // Normalize for center
            progressToCenter = Math.abs(0.5f - yRelativeToCenterOffset);
            // Adjust to the maximum scale
            progressToCenter = Math.min(progressToCenter, MAX_ICON_PROGRESS);

            child.setScaleX(1 - progressToCenter);
            child.setScaleY(1 - progressToCenter);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the adapter:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuRecyclerViewAdapter extends WearableRecyclerView.Adapter<MenuRecyclerViewAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends WearableRecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView1,mImageView2,mImageView3,mImageView4;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            mImageView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            mImageView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            mImageView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        }
    }
    public MenuRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;

    }
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        holder.mImageView1.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mImageView2.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mImageView3.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mImageView4.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

}
```

the `xml` file for my items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.CircularProgressLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:src="@drawable/homeicon4"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:src="@drawable/bypass3"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:src="@drawable/dualflow3"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:src="@drawable/isolation3"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.wear.widget.CircularProgressLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have experience with _WearableRecyclerView_, but if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView) you will see that it extends from _RecyclerView_, so, yes, I would expect it to behave largely like a _RecyclerView_.

Comment: yeah I played around a bit, my problem is I can't get it to appear in the same way. I have added a few imagebuttons but they're lined up vertically rather than in a curved manner like in the documentation and I don't know why

Comment: I see and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists#creating) doesn't help?

Comment: These I have included in my activity so I'm not aware what I might have done wrong, I upload my code above if you want to take a look, I added the adapter and the xml file of my items.

Comment: Posting the code may give someone a clue about what's going on to give you an answer. btw, you don't need to post the imports or the boiler plate XML code like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and the name space declarations.

Comment: Yeah I did post it under the "Edit" in bold. Thanks for the tip anyway.